Methods to Find Perfect Squares for Without Exhaustive Search?
I'm trying to find values of $n$ such that the expression $n^2 + 370730n + 444858$ is a perfect square, i.e.,
$$
n^2 + 370730n + 444858 = k^2
$$
One known solution is $n = 15859$, which gives:
$$
15859^2 + 370730 \times 15859 + 444858 = 6131359809 = 78303^2
$$
Are there any methods to find or approximate such solutions other than brute-force testing of values for $n$ one by one? For example, could methods from number theory, Pell's equations, or other approaches be used to make this process more efficient?

Start by completing the square

… then factor $2^{35}-1$.

Same method as here in the dupe.

Complete the square to get $(N+k)(N-k)=N^2-k^2=(n+185365)^2-k^2$
$=185365^2-444858=34359738367=31\times71\times127\times122921$.
Now solve
$N+k=71\times127\times122921, N-k=31; N+k=31\times127\times122921, N-k=71$
$N+k=31\times71\times122921, N-k=127; N+k=31\times71\times127, N-k=122921$;
$N+k=127\times122921, N-k=31\times71; N+k=71\times122921, N-k=31\times127$;
$N+k=31\times122921, N-k=71\times127; N+k=34359738367, N-k=1$
and note that $N^2-k^2=(-N)^2-k^2=N^2-(-k)^2=(-N)^2-(-k)^2$
to get all the solutions.
The solution you gave was from $N+k=31\times71\times127, N-k=122921$.

Surely you know this is a duplicate

Why didn't you say so earlier, before I typed it all out?

OK here you were able to factor 2**35 - 1 but when you don't know factorization of it is there a method to approximate solution for example ?

Wolfram alpha can factor numbers of this size
